# ion infinite scroll doesn't work with ion segment

Tags: ionic2

I'm trying to use ion-infinite-scroll with ion-segment, it works when the main ion-segment loads but when i switch between segments ion-infinite-scroll and 
ion-segment stop displaying data.
Help,
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

ion-infinite-scroll does not work with ion-segment if nested under ngSwitch (or ngIf). If think it will be fixed by the ionic team, but in the meantime I use ngClass as a workaround:

```
<div [ngClass]="{'hidden': segment !== 'mySegment' }">
 content
</div>

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```